# Paste and Merge Formatting in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to work on a paste and merge formatting macro in microsoft word. I am constantly copying from a website and then pasting from that website into Word. Unfortunately, the website format is always:

Text

Citation

I want the format to be:

"Text." Citation.

My code currently is

```
Sub Paste_Citation()
' Paste_Citation Macro
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.TypeText Text:="."

End Sub
```

I cannot figure out how to a) to not have a paragraph space between the text and the citation, b)put parentheses around the text. If the text does not have a period at the end, then format like "blah blah". Otherwise, "blah blah." and c) not include the text if the text only includes spaces and a period. I know that I need to do an if statement for c, but I am not very familiar with VBA in Word. Could someone walk through the process with me?

Edit #1

```
x = Selection.PasteAndFormat(wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)
'trying to set x equal to the pasted formatted value
Dim Txt As String
Dim Cit As String
Txt = Split(x, Chr(182))
'trying to split the text based on the paragraph symbol
'I am confused on what I need to do from there
```

Edit #2
I have been working on it longer, and I think that I am pretty close. I figured out how to paste the info and merge the formats, as well as how to delete the paragraph break. My issue now is that I cannot figure out how to have it put quotations around the first paragraph, bring the cursor to the end of the paste, and add a period at the end.

```
Sub PasteCitation()
'Modified code from http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-46321.html
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Txt As Range
Set Txt = Selection.Range
Txt.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatSurroundingFormattingWithEmphasis)

With Txt.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True

     'Replace single paragraph breaks with a space
    .Text = "([!^13])([^13])([!^13])"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 \3"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The red line of your programming should be to assign the downloaded 'Text' and 'Citation' to variables, say

```
Dim Txt As String
Dim Cit As String

Txt = "Whatever you scraped from tre website"
Cit = "Whatever else you scraped from the web"
```

With that accomplished you can start manipulating each of the strings and then place them in your document where you want, perhaps at the location of your current selection.

When you follow this method you may come to individual questions which can be answered quickly. Meanwhile, avoid the use of `On Error Resume Next` while you don't know what error might crop up and how you want to deal with it.

Comment: I tried to go off what you said and looked at some different functions to split the copied values, but I got stuck on how to split the clipboard text, but still merge formatting with word.

Comment: I am still having trouble with the quotations because I cannot figure out how to split the code based on the paragraph, but I have been able to at least delete the paragraph break between the text and the citation.

Comment: It seems like you have arrived at the last paragraph of my above advice. That is good progress. If you think it was good advice you should accept it and follow it. You accept it by marking the answer as "accepted". You follow it by asking a new question in a way that it is possible to give an answer.